# parsing multiple elements from a node without knowing their names

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

This is certainly a very simple question, but I've already searched through 2 pages of Google results and still haven't found an answer.

So basically, I have an XML like this:

```
<section name="section1">
     <set name="set1">value1</set>
     <set name="set2">value2</set>
     <set name="set3">value3</set>
<section>
```

There are multiple sections of this structure.

What I want to do is parse this into a dictionary without knowing the names of those "sets" exactly. So, after parsing this should look like this:

```
section1[set1]  <--- should contain "value1"
```

The same for set2 and so on.

How can I achieve this using LINQ to XML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var section1 = xdoc.Descendants("set") // or xdoc.Root.Elements()
                   .ToDictionary(s => (string)s.Attribute("name"),
                                 s => (string)s);

var set2 = section1["set2"]; // "value2"
```

Comment: OK, thanks, it works, but if I have multiple sections (and thus multiple set elements in different sections) all set's will be placed in a dictionary. How to choose set elements only from a specific section?

Comment: @szczurcio use following code to get `set` elements from specific section `xdoc.Descendants("section").Where(s => (string)s.Attribute("name") == "section1").Elements()`. ALso you can use xpath: `xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//section[@name='section1']/set")`

Answer (score 2):

here  how you can find  an  element with a specific  section

```
TextReader txtReader  = new StringReader(xml);
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(txtReader);
var section1 = xDoc.Descendants("section").Where(elt=>elt.Attribute("name").ToString()=="section1").Descendants("set") 
       .ToDictionary(s => (string)s.Attribute("name"),
                     s => (string)s);
```